# count number of instances django template

Tags: django, templates

I've read all the other answers posted with some saying you can and some saying you can't so I tried. What I'm trying to do is iterate my array and if the object's id matches, increment the counter and display it later. I have it set up like this:

```
 {% with elect_count=1 %}
        {% for device in devices %}

                {% if device.ixDeviceType.ixDeviceClass_id == 3 %}
                    {{ elect_count|add:1 }}//increment the counter
                {% endif %}

        {% endfor %}
        <li style="list-style: none;" class="padding5">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash" style="color: yellow; font-size: larger;"></span>
            <span name="meter-count">{{ elect_count }}</span>//display total number of elect_count
            <ul id="meter-summary">
            </ul>
        </li>
    {% endwith %}
```

but when I run this, it displays `1 1 1 1` instead of incrementing this elect_count variable and when I do `{{ elect_count }}` it's 0

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot save the counter in template, but you could do it in views and pass it in context:

views.py

```
def view_function(request):
    elect_count = 0
    for device in devices:
        if device.ixDeviceType.ixDeviceClass_id == 3:
            elect_count += 1
    context['elect_count'] = elect_count
```

Comment: There is, because instead of counting in the template, you count in views and pass the result in the context. You shouldn't put such logic in template, template is only for displaying purpose.

Comment: I was aware but I didn't really want to end up with like 50 variables being passed in my request context so I thought I could do it that way since jinja2 allows it, but realized django default isn't jinja2

Comment: Put all counts in a data structure like a list or a dictionary, then loop the data structure to get each count.

Comment: ahhh I see what you're getting at. Thanks